# How to map the values based on other column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I need to fill NaN values in column but it should be based on other column. I have dataframe like this:

df

```
Id             Level           Country       Gender          Age           Model
1               0                Uk            M             20             BMW
1               1                NaN           NaN           NaN            Audi
1               2                NaN           NaN           NaN            VW
2               0                US            F             50             BMW
3               0                UK            F             40             Audi
```

So in my second column there are levels which atleast describe the different models. I want to fill NaN values in columns `Country`  `Gender`  and `Age`  with the value which is at level 0. So, my desired output should look like this:

```
Id             Level           Country       Gender          Age           Model
1               0                Uk            M             20             BMW
1               1                Uk            M             20             Audi
1               2                Uk            M             20             VW
2               0                US            F             50             BMW
3               0                UK            F             40             Audi
```

Comment: Is `Level=0` is unique per `Id`? i.e does each `Id` have only one row per `Id` ? Is there any case of `Id` having no `level=0` ?

Comment: There is always level 0 which is always first level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if level 0 is always the first per Id, then you can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) with `first` and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to fill nan:

```
df_f = df.combine_first(df.groupby('Id')[['Country', 'Gender', 'Age']].transform('first'))
print (df_f)
    Age Country Gender  Id  Level Model
0  20.0      Uk      M   1      0   BMW
1  20.0      Uk      M   1      1  Audi
2  20.0      Uk      M   1      2    VW
3  50.0      US      F   2      0   BMW
4  40.0      UK      F   3      0  Audi
```

Comment: Thanks. I didnt thought in that way.. :)